# How return true or false from a function in code using a constant array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm suppose to return true or false if the sum of even numbers in an array is greater than the sum of odd numbers in the same array. My program keeps returning true regardless if I change the elements of the array so it can return false. It seems very simple but I cannot seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

My code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    bool die(const string & msg);
    bool morePos(const unsigned ar[], unsigned els);


    int main(){
        unsigned a[5] = { 7, 7, 7, 2, 4 };
        cout << morePos(a, 5) << endl;

    }

    bool die(const string & msg){
        cout << "fatal error: " << msg << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    bool morePos(const unsigned ar[], unsigned els){
        unsigned a[5] = { 7, 7, 7, 2, 4 };
        unsigned sumOdd = 0;
        unsigned sumEven = 0;
            if (a[5] % 2 == 0){
                sumEven += a[5];
            }
            if (a[5] % 2 != 0){
                sumOdd += a[5];
            }

        if (sumEven > sumOdd){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, your function does not even work with the array you pass from `main`. Your function works with its own internal array `a`. For which reason changing the array in `main` will not have any effect. Secondly, why are you trying to access `a[5]`? `a[5]` is a non-existent element of the array. Your array has elements from `a[0]` to `a[4]`. There's no `a[5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Iterate over the elements array.
2. For each element of the array, check whether the element is odd or even.
3. If it is odd, accumulate it `sumOdd`. Otherwise, accumulate it in `sumEven`.

```
bool morePos(const unsigned ar[], unsigned els){

   unsigned sumOdd = 0;
   unsigned sumEven = 0;
   for ( unsigned i = 0; i < els; ++i )
   {
      if (a[i] % 2 == 0){
         sumEven += a[i];
      }
      else {
         sumOdd += a[i];
      }
   }

   return (sumEven > sumOdd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things need to be fixed:

- You are passing `ar` to `morePos`, so there is no need to re-declare the array `a`
- You need a loop to go through all elements, not only look at element `5`
- A `for` loop would be good for this purpose. Use zero as the beginning index and `els` as the limit. Better yet, rename `els` as `count` or `numElements` or something descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (a[5] % 2 == 0){
        sumEven += a[5];
    }
```

to

```
    for (int i = 0; i < els; ++i)
        if (ar[i] % 2 == 0)
            sumEven += ar[i];
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't look good. 
First you are not using ar (received as parameter) but array a.
Second and most important:

- There is no loop going through all elements of a
- a[5] is an out-of-bound error. a has 5 elements, from 0 to 4.